# How to set type in Factory pattern in which exists multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript, factory-pattern

There are like these types

```js
interface A {
  id: number
  name: string
  patternA: patternA[]
}

interface B {
  id: number
  name: string
  patternB: patternB[]
}

interface C {
  id: number
  name: string
  patternC: patternC[]
  city: string
}
```

and there is factory method

```js
const factory = (type, data: /**  what should I write?? **/) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'first':
      return createHogeA(data)
    case 'second':
      return createHogeB(data)
    case 'third':
      return createHogeC(data)
    default:
      return
  }
}

const createHogeA = (data: A) => somefunctionA(data)
const createHogeB = (data: B) => somefunctionB(data)
const createHogeC = (data: C) => somefunctionC(data)
```

#### What I've tried so far

1. Set type like this, but then appears error because it's possible that each datas type could pass to each functions

```js
const factory = (type, data: A | B | C) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'first':
      return createHogeA(data)
    case 'second':
      return createHogeB(data)
    case 'third':
      return createHogeC(data)
    default:
      return
  }
}
```

2. Create base interface

```js
interface base {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

But then honestly I didn't have idea

Comment: how do you intend to call your factory? where does `type` come from?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to use the `as` keyword to tell the compiler which of the interfaces the `data` object satisfies when calling either of the functions.

```js
const factory = (type: string, data: A | B | C) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'first':
      return createHogeA(data as A)
    case 'second':
      return createHogeB(data as B)
    case 'third':
      return createHogeC(data as C)
    default:
      return
  }
}
```

You could also use guards to determine which interface `data` satisfies

```js
const isA = (data: any): data is A => {
  return (data as A).patternA !== undefined;
}

const isB = (data: any): data is B => {
  return (data as B).patternB !== undefined;
}

const isC = (data: any): data is C => {
  return (data as C).patternC !== undefined && (data as C).city !== undefined;
}

const factory = (_type: string, data: A | B | C) => {
  if(isA(data)) {
    createHogeA(data)
  }
  // Rest of code here
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it resolved, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps via type union discrimination:

```
interface A {
  type: 'A'
  id: number
  name: string
  patternA: patternA[]
}

interface B {
  type: 'B'
  id: number
  name: string
  patternB: patternB[]
}

interface C {
  type: 'C'
  id: number
  name: string
  patternC: patternC[]
  city: string
}

type ABC = A | B | C;

const factory = (data: ABC) => {
  switch (data.type) {
    case 'A':
      return createHogeA(data)
    case 'B':
      return createHogeB(data)
    case 'C':
      return createHogeC(data)
    default:
      return
  }
}
```